# Insert an image to cell by NPOI

Tags: asp.net, image, excel, npoi

I am using NPOI to generate excel file. My requirement is insert an image to cell. However i having a problem nw. How can i insert an image in only one cell by using NPOI?Did anyone solve this trouble before?

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeWorkbook();
        ISheet sheet1 = hssfworkbook.CreateSheet("PictureSheet");


        HSSFPatriarch patriarch = (HSSFPatriarch)sheet1.CreateDrawingPatriarch();

        //create the anchor
        HSSFClientAnchor anchor;
        anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor(0, 0, 0, 255, 2, 2, 4, 6);
        anchor.AnchorType = 0;




        picture.LineStyle = HSSFPicture.OBJECT_TYPE_LINE;
        WriteToFile();
    }

    private  int LoadImage(string path, HSSFWorkbook wb)
    {

        FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[file.Length];
        file.Read(buffer, 0, (int)file.Length);
        return wb.AddPicture(buffer, PictureType.JPEG);

    }
```

Comment: _"i having a trouble nw"_ What does that mean? Please explain exactly what kind of trouble/error you have.

Comment: @user998405 you can follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705711/how-i-can-place-an-image-just-in-one-cell-using-npoi) having similar scenario as of yours

Comment: Duplicate question. 
Please go to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705711/how-i-can-place-an-image-just-in-one-cell-using-npoi][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705711/how-i-can-place-an-image-just-in-one-cell-using-npoi